# graphviz circle subgraph

Tags: graphviz, dot, subgraph

I have a graphviz representation with 7 subgraph clusters. In each subgraph there is around 20 nodes interconnected.

Each subgraph have 3 to 10 links with one or more cluster (one node in cluster 1 go to another node in cluster 2 for example).

I would like to place all the subgraph in a circle presentation so I can easily trace the link between them. Is there a way to achieve this ? Or at least is there a way to fix position of each subgraph ?

Hope you can help me.
Tahnk you.

Answer (score 0):

Rendering circular subgraph clusters is not supported in Graphviz. However, you can use rectangular subgraphs to encapsulate nodes. Here's an example:

```
digraph G {
    layout="fdp";
    node [margin=0, fontcolor=blue, fontsize=18, width=0.4, shape=circle, style=filled]
  
    subgraph cluster_A {
        label = "Cluster A";
        a1 ["shape"="point", "color"="blue", "style"="filled", fontsize="40"]
        a2 ["shape"="point", "color"="blue", "style"="filled", fontsize="40"]
        a3 ["shape"="point", "color"="blue", "style"="filled", fontsize="40"]        
    }

    subgraph cluster_B {
        label = "Cluster B";
        b1 ["shape"="point", "color"="green", "style"="filled", fontsize="40"]
        b2 ["shape"="point", "color"="green", "style"="filled", fontsize="40"]
        b3 ["shape"="point", "color"="green", "style"="filled", fontsize="40"]   
    }
    
    subgraph cluster_C {
        label = "Cluster C";
        c1 ["shape"="point", "color"="red", "style"="filled", fontsize="40"]
        c2 ["shape"="point", "color"="red", "style"="filled", fontsize="40"]
        c3 ["shape"="point", "color"="red", "style"="filled", fontsize="40"]
    }
    
    a1 -> b1
    a2 -> b2
    a3 -> b3
    c1 -> b1
    c2 -> b2
    c3 -> b3
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to do this if there are nodes that belong to more than 1 subgraph?

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of rank attribute. Here is one possibility. Off-course, you can explore more possibilities with your own code.

```
digraph trial {

subgraph _1 {
 rank="same";
 p0 [label="p0"];
 p1 [label="p1"];
 p2 [label="p2"];
 p0-> p1 -> p2 -> p0;
}
subgraph _2 {   
 rank="same";  
 p3 [label="p3"];
 p4 [label="p4"];
 p3 -> p4 -> p3;
}
subgraph _3 {   
 rank="same";  
 p6 [label="p6"];
 p5 [label="p5"];
 p7 [label="p5"];
 p5 -> p6 -> p7 -> p5;
}

p3 -> p1 [color="red"];
p2 -> p5 [color="red"];
p6 -> p4 [color="red"];
}
```

[image]

You can read about rank here: http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html